# Google maps api, gecode. Trying to geocode a language specific address

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps

I'm sure this question has been asked somewhere, but for the life of me i can't seem to find it..

I have an address in "København S" denmark, that i am trying to geocode so i can place a marker on my map. However i get the zero results error, and i can see that

> "København S"

has been changed to

> `"K&#xF8;benhavn S"`

with the hex. 
I'm sure this is fairly easy to get around, but i have been trying the past hour and i think im making it to complicated for myself. Is there an easy workaround to specify the character set i want it to use rather than it being in partly hex?

Here is my code, the error msg and the msg with the hex.

```
function geocodeAddress() {
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
if (geoIndex < addressesToGeo.length) {
    var addressSplit = addressesToGeo[geoIndex].split("SPLIT"); // temp
    alert(addressSplit[0]); // second alert msg image
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': addressSplit[0] }, makeCallBack(parseInt(addressSplit[1])));
    ++geoIndex;
}
else {
    clearInterval(geoTimer);
}
```

}

[image]
[image]

Comment: Geocoder handles all encoding out of the box, it could be your browser or string operations that are escaping those characters.Try your location here http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/ehPup/ check if it works for you.